# Adding application config file to web.config

Tags: iis-7, web-config

I am running IIS7.
I have a 3rd party dll that has its own config file.  My understanding is that IIS7 will not read this config file and that I have to add it to the server web.config file.

However I get errors when adding a particular node.
In the dll.config it has:

```
<configuration>
  <dllSettings>
    --- bunch of settings....
  </dllSettings>
</configuration>
```

So I added that same node into my web.config file...

Is there a parent node that I should add this to in my web.config?

Answer (score 0):

When I have to add more config file.  This is how I defined in the Web.Config

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="[NAMESPACE].[PROJECT].Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>

</configSections>

<applicationSettings>
        <[NAMESPACE].[PROJECT].Properties.Settings configSource="[NAMESPACE].[PROJECT].dll.settings.config"/>
</applicationSettings>

...
</configuration>
```

This is what I have in my other Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<[PROJECT].Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="[NAME]" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Anything</value>
    </setting>
</[PROJECT].Properties.Settings>
```

Comment: I still get errors when I add <applicationSettings></applicationSettings> right after my <configSections> node.

Comment: I get Visual Studio error that I am unable to debug on the web server. See help for common configuration errors...  Then my application doesnt run...
<RelayHealth.ATS.Services.Properties.Settings>
  <!-- The following setting is for whether perform real-time vs batch transaction: Y for batch; N for real-time-->
    <batchTransaction>Y</batchTransaction>
more settings.... then the end of the node.